# Find the square root of n

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

The task:

> Given a real number n, find the square root of n. For example, given n
>   = 9, return 3.

My solution:

```
const findRoot = n => n >=  0 ? n ** .5 : void 0;

console.log(findRoot(9));
```

Is this some kind of trick question? What's there to solve? Did I miss something?

Comment: -1 is a real number.  You might also be meant to solve it without using `sqrt` or floating-point exponentiation.

Comment: It’s a binary search question.